# how to change the google map marker dynamically with the model value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, marker

im showing one blue marker while voltage is not 0 , i want to show marker as red marker while voltage is 0.

if `@Model.RVoltage==0` or `@Model.YVoltage==0` or `@Model.BVoltage == 0` then marker icon should be red.

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.804270950051844, 122.18359432304942),
            myOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            },
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: @Model.RVoltage==0 || @Model.YVoltage==0 ||  @Model.BVoltage==0 ?'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png' : 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png',
            label: "1",
        });
        var contentString = 'no 102';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: icon: @Model.RVoltage==0 || @Model.RVoltage==0 ||  @Model.BVoltage==0 ?'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png' : 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png',

is this line correct. can we write like this?

Comment: yes this is correct let me check..is there any error?